# Table chart in google chart adding button

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawVisualization2(dataValues, chartTitle, columnNames, categoryCaption) {
            if (dataValues.length < 1)
                return;
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[0]);
            data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[1]);
            data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[2]);
            data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[3]);
            data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[4]);
            data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[5]);
            data.addColumn('button', 'test');


            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([dataValues[i].Value1, dataValues[i].Value2, dataValues[i].Value3, dataValues[i].Value4, dataValues[i].Value5, dataValues[i].Value6, '<input type="button" value="test" />']);
            }

            var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '####%' });
            formatter.format(data, 5);

            var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'Container1',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': columnNames.split(',')[1],
                    'ui': {
                        'labelStacking': 'horizontal',
                        'allowTyping': false,
                        'allowMultiple': false,
                        'caption': categoryCaption,
                        'label': columnNames.split(',')[2]
                    }
                }
            });


            var table2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'Table',
                'containerId': 'TableContainer2',

                'options': {
                    'width': '895px',
                    'page': 'enable',
                    'pageSize': 5

                }
            });

            new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('PieChartExample2')).bind([categoryPicker2], [table2]).draw(data);
            visualization.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });
        }



     </script>
```

Brief code to draw a table chart;Normal table chart coming proper;but when i add the button it goes wrong.Trying to add the button to table chart i am not able to do..can anyone help me to do so...Thank you...any advice or links.

Answer (score 3):

The way you declared and insertion of button is the problem.

**Declaration :**

*`data.addColumn('string', '');` //For button column*

**Insertion :**

```
{v:'ButtonName', f:'<input type="button" value="test" />'}
```

So in your case complete insertion is as follows,

*`data.addRow([dataValues[i].Value1, dataValues[i].Value2, dataValues[i].Value3, dataValues[i].Value4, dataValues[i].Value5, dataValues[i].Value6, {v:'ButtonName', f:'<input type="button" value="test" />'}]);`*

Please refer for more details on [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)

Comment: Works! But, as @user1613402 points out, allowHtml must be set to true.

Answer (score 3):

To add a button to a table chart of Google Visualization :

```
    var buttonColumnIndex=data.addColumn('string','ButtonColumn');
```

You can add button to a particular cell in that column by:

```
    data.setCell(rowIndex,buttonColumnIndex,'<input type="button" value="test"/>');
```

For this to work,**allowHtml** should be set to true.